# Solution to Euler Problem 5: My code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, math

I have a problem with Project Euler challenge 5. The challenge is based on finding the smallest positive number that is divisible by all the numbers from 1 to 20. This is my code:

```
let i = 1;
function myFunction (num) {
  return i % num == 0
}
while (true) {
  let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
  if (arr.every(myFunction)) {
    console.log(i)
    break;
  } else {
    i++
    continue;
  }
}
```

The code up to number 16 works fine (720720), but once I add another number to the array, in order (16, 17, 18, ...) it doesn't work anymore. I don't know why, I'm very new to programming. If you could instruct me.

Comment: I'm not into mathematics, do you mean that is divisible and gives an integer as the result of the division ?

Comment: Look, for example: 1 is divisible by 1 because the remainder equals 0, 2 is divisible by 1 and 2 for the same reason, 6 is divisible by 3, 2 and 1 because the % equals 0. 2520 is divisible by 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 because the % equals 0. No number other than this one can operate with the division operator without giving decimals in the context where it is divided by all the numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer above takes way to long, like he said, quite a few seconds.

This code is longer but takes less than a second to come up with the result.

```
const divisibleByAllToN = (n) => {
  const twoToN = Array(n - 1)
    .fill(2)
    .map((item, index) => item + index);

  let numbersToBeMultiplied = twoToN.filter((item) => {
    for (var i = 2; i < item; i++) if (item % i === 0) return false;
    return item > 1;
  });

  numbersToBeMultiplied = numbersToBeMultiplied.map((item) => {
    let value = item;
    while (value * item <= n) {
      value = value * item;
    }
    return value;
  });
  return numbersToBeMultiplied.reduce((acc, val) => acc * val);
};

divisibleByAllToN(20);
```

Answer (score 0):

solved :

you need to return a **condition** in **myFunction** in order for array.every to work properly :

```js
let i = 1;
function myFunction (num) {
  var result = i / num
  return parseInt(result) === result // condition HERE to check if result is an int
}
while (true) {
  let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
  if (arr.every(myFunction)) {
    console.log(i)
    break;
  } else {
    i++
    continue;
  }
}
```

doing this we get (after about 20 seconds) the right result : 232792560

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm sorry. I asked the wrong question, this is the right condition: return i % num == 0.  The code checks if "i" is divisible by all the numbers from 1 to 20.